# Mixing explicit class specialization and class method specialization?

Tags: c++, templates

So I've got a class that wants to instantiated for exactly one of two classes. I declare it in the header:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass {
 public:
  bool DoSomethingGeneric();
  bool DoSomethingTSpecific();
};
```

Since I don't want to place the method definitions in the header, I instead place them in the implementation file, and perform an explicit specialization. While the `DoSomethingGeneric` method can be defined generically using a template, the `DoSomethingTSpecific` requires two separate implementations, one for each of the two possible classes for which I want to instantiate `MyClass`:

```
template <class T>
bool MyClass<T>::DoSomethingGeneric() {
  // Generic code
}

template <>
bool MyClass<ClassA>::DoSomethingTSpecific() {
  // ClassA-specific implementation
}

template <>
bool MyClass<ClassB>::DoSomethingTSpecific() {
  // ClassB-specific implementation
}
```

Now, riddle me this: where do I place the explicit specialization? If I place it after my template definitions (like I usually do with specializations of purely-generic classes), clang says:

```
explicit specialization of 'MyClass<ClassA>' after instantiation
```

This message is accompanied by a pointer to the line where `DoSomethingTSpecific` is defined. This makes sense. My understanding is that the explicit specialization of the `DoSomethingTSpecific` method counts as an implicit specialization.

Meanwhile, if I place the specializations after all the template definitions, I see:

```
no function template matches function template specialization 'DoSomethingTSpecific'
```

This one is kind of a mystery to me.

Any thoughts? How can I have an explicit class-level specialization and explicit method specialization?

Comment: can't reproduce https://godbolt.org/g/zAlT8e

Comment: That reproduction is unrelated to the question. This one reproduces it: https://godbolt.org/g/kbcRK3 Note that addition of the explicit class specialization. Moving that specialization reproduces both errors.

Comment: How about this https://godbolt.org/g/umiA5o ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C++ Standard **§14.7.3(5) *Explicit specialization***  (*emphasis mine*):

> Members of an explicitly specialized class template are
>   defined in the same manner as members of normal classes, and **not using the `template<>` syntax**.

Example:

```
template <> // specialization for classA
class MyClass<ClassA> {
public:
    bool DoSomethingTSpecific(); // must be declared here
};

// template<> is not used here
bool MyClass<ClassA>::DoSomethingTSpecific() {
  // ClassA-specific implementation
}
```

Demo:

http://cpp.sh/3tc2g